# Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

My application works fine but I have the following error:

> Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string')

Below my code:

```
public login(userData: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post("/api/users/login", userData)
      .map(token => this.saveToken(token));
}


private saveToken(token: string): string {
    localStorage.setItem("car_auth", token);
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error say, you assign `Object` to `string`.

Try to replace your code like that:

```
public login(userData: any): Observable<string> {
    return this.http
      .post("/api/users/login", userData)
      .map((token: string) => this.saveToken(token));
}


private saveToken(token: string): string {
    localStorage.setItem("car_auth", token);
    return token;
}
```

Comment: it say cannot find name "token"

Comment: .map((token: string )=> this.saveToken(token));

Answer (score 0):

Transcompiler needs a hint of what your  `http.post` returns because you typed the argument of `saveToken`. Transcompiler wants to make sure you're passing a string.

add explicit type :

```
public login(userData: any) {
  return this.http
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .map((token: string) => this.saveToken(token));
}
```

Comment: it say cannot find name "token"

Comment: its work thanks first i create typo mistake thanks alot